# Load string as xml from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml, string, select

Im trying to get a string from a mysql database and handle it like an xml object, navigation etc.

i got an sql table with a "longtext" field wich stores my xml file as a simple string. I do the select on the database and i get the string but only the info, not the tags etc.

Is there any way to select a string from a mysql database (xml formated), get it to php and work with it as a xml file ?

thanks in advance

Comment: have you looked at http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting the tags?  How are you viewing the XML? In a browser?  Is the http header set for XML?  If you are viewing it in a browser it may be trying to parse it as XHTML and therefore showing you only the text nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve the string from the database then load it into [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php):

```
$xmlObj = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
```

From there you can manipulate the xml object with the SimpleXML libray.

If you are retrieving the string and echoing it to a browser, and you only see the content of the tags (with no `<>`) then that is because the browser is interpreting them as HTML tags. If you use the browsers view->source you'll see the plain XML as a string.

Comment: as you say if i echo the content it apperars well formated in the debug console.

i amb trying what you say but i dont get any data from the xml.

    $xmlstring = $server['xml'];  

    $xmlObj = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
    $test_object = $xmlObj->Clave->Email;
    echo "$test_object";

Comment: seems that the comand "$xmlObj = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);" is not working for me. Is there any necesary include or something that i need ??

Comment: is there any error? What happens when you `print_r($xmlObj);`?

Comment: ok finaly solved, problem was that the xml string was not well formated... anyway i used "$obj = simplexml_load_string($server['xml']);" to get the XML object